# How to change my name into columns using sql

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the best query to split name into columns?

ie. if my name is VELOCITY in one column.

How can i split it as

```
V
E
L
O
C
I
T
Y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just have a single row then:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR('VELOCITY', LEVEL, 1) AS ch
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH('VELOCITY');
```

Which outputs:

> | CH |
> | --- |
> | V |
> | E |
> | L |
> | O |
> | C |
> | I |
> | T |
> | Y |

---

If you have multiple input rows then, from Oracle 12, you can use a `LATERAL` join:

```sql
SELECT c.ch
FROM   table_name t
       INNER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT SUBSTR(t.value, LEVEL, 1) AS ch
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(t.value)
       ) c
       ON (t.value IS NOT NULL);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=91a7b7533c0c78f433e49438162a1142)*